# Angular2 cannot find module: './class' within docker

Tags: angular, docker, npm

I am working on building an automated deployment platform for an angular2 app using Gitlab and Docker.  The project is based on https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/

I've made some changes to the template project, namely adding some of my own services and models.  In my `app` directory I've added a `servics` and `models` directory.

services/example.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Example } from '../models/Example';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

  private BaseUrl = 'http://localhost:6969/api/1.0/example'


  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  Example(Payload: string) {
    //do stuff
  }

}
```

models/example.ts

```
export class Example{
    ID: number;
    //etc
}
```

Docker Image: node

script:

```
npm install
npm run build:prod:aot
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Angular and Bootstrap 4 Admin Template.",
  "author": "Akveo <contact@akveo.com>",
  "homepage": "http://akveo.github.io/App/",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/App.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/App/issues"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "changelog": "standard-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:hmr": "ng serve --hmr",
    "start:aot": "ng serve --aot",
    "start:prod": "ng serve --prod",
    "start:prod:aot": "ng serve --prod --aot",
    "build": "npm run clean:dist && ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod",
    "build:prod:aot": "npm run build:prod -- --aot",
    "build:ci": "npm run build:prod && npm run build:prod:aot",
    "build:demo": "npm run build:prod:aot -- --base-href \"http://akveo.com/App/\"",
    "test": "ng test -sr",
    "test:coverage": "npm run clean:coverage && ng test -sr -cc",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/app/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:coverage": "npm run rimraf -- coverage",
    "docs:deploy": "wintersmith build -C docs && gh-pages -d docs/build",
    "docs:serve": "wintersmith preview -C docs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.1.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "6.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
    "amcharts3": "github:amcharts/amcharts3",
    "ammap3": "github:amcharts/ammap3",
    "angular2-datatable": "0.6.0",
    "animate.css": "3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "chart.js": "1.1.1",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "chroma-js": "1.3.3",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.3.1",
    "google-maps": "3.2.1",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "1.3.8",
    "leaflet": "0.7.7",
    "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.6",
    "ng2-completer": "1.3.1",
    "ng2-handsontable": "0.48.0",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "4.0.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.0.3",
    "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-alpha.5",
    "ngx-uploader": "2.2.5",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.7.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@types/fullcalendar": "2.7.40",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.41",
    "@types/jquery.slimscroll": "1.3.30",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.61",
    "@types/node": "6.0.69",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "0.12.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "standard-changelog": "1.0.1",
    "stylelint": "7.10.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.2",
    "tslint": "5.2.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "4.0.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "0.9.6",
    "typescript": "2.3.2",
    "typogr": "0.6.6",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "wintersmith": "2.2.5",
    "wintersmith-sassy": "1.1.0"
  }
}
```

my script runs successfully on windows, but is unsuccessful when run in the node docker container.

error:

```
ERROR in /builds/mibzman/App/web/src/app/services/request.service.ts (4,27): Cannot find module '/../models/Example'.

ERROR in /builds/mibzman/App/web/src/app/models/survey.ts (1,27): Cannot find module './Example'.

ERROR in /builds/mibzman/App/web/src/app/models/survey.ts (2,34): Cannot find module './OtherModel'.

ERROR in /builds/mibzman/App/web/src/app/models/survey.ts (3,32): Cannot find module './SomeOtherModel'.

ERROR in /builds/mibzman/App/web/src/app/models/surveyresponse.ts (1,24): Cannot find module './Answer'.

ERROR in /builds/mibzman/App/web/src/app/pages/new/new.component.ts (5,27): Cannot find module '../../models/Example'.

ERROR in /builds/mibzman/App/web/src/app/pages/new/new.service.ts (11,27): Cannot find module '../../models/Example'.

ERROR in /builds/mibzman/App/web/src/app/pages/new/components/ExampleForm/ExampleForm.component.ts (3,27): Cannot find module '../../../../models/Example'.

ERROR in ./src/app/pages/new/components/ExampleForm/ExampleForm.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../models/Example' in '/builds/mibzman/App/web/src/app/pages/new/components/ExampleForm'
 @ ./src/app/pages/new/components/ExampleForm/ExampleForm.component.ts 2:0-57
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/pages/new/new.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/pages/new/new.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir async
 @ ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

npm info lifecycle App@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-78-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/builds/mibzman/App/web/node_modules/.bin/npm" "run" "build" "--" "--prod" "--aot"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! App@1.0.0 build: `npm run clean:dist && ng build "--prod" "--aot"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the App@1.0.0 build script 'npm run clean:dist && ng build "--prod" "--aot"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the App package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run clean:dist && ng build "--prod" "--aot"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs App
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls App
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /builds/mibzman/App/web/npm-debug.log

npm info lifecycle App@1.0.0~build:prod: Failed to exec build:prod script
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-78-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/builds/mibzman/App/web/node_modules/.bin/npm" "run" "build:prod" "--" "--aot"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! App@1.0.0 build:prod: `npm run build -- --prod "--aot"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the App@1.0.0 build:prod script 'npm run build -- --prod "--aot"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the App package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build -- --prod "--aot"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs App
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls App
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /builds/mibzman/App/web/npm-debug.log

npm info lifecycle App@1.0.0~build:prod:aot: Failed to exec build:prod:aot script
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-78-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build:prod:aot"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! App@1.0.0 build:prod:aot: `npm run build:prod -- --aot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the App@1.0.0 build:prod:aot script 'npm run build:prod -- --aot'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the App package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build:prod -- --aot
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs App
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls App
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-05-28T00_13_01_172Z-debug.log
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

What is actually causing this error?

Comment: You said you added the services and models directory, are they also being mounted in the container?

Comment: yes, all files are present when the docker container runs

Comment: strange that it looks like it's looking from the root in `Cannot find module '/../models/Example'.`. Sorry, I don't think I can help you.